# WordPress Login redirect_to not working

Tags: php, redirect, wordpress

I'm working on a web site with WordPress 3.7.1 and trying to redirect a user upon login via the redirect_to URL parameter.

I've verified that the login form backend sees the redirect_to GET parameter, and that the login submission includes the redirect_to POST value...but thats where things don't work.

**Removed link and user credentials**

Upon login (for both my Admin acct and the Subscriber acct provided in this post), the user is taken to the WP dashboard instead of the URL in the redirect_to parameter.

I do have the allowed_redirect_hosts being set, with the following code in a custom plugin file (which is pretty much just this).

```
add_filter( 'allowed_redirect_hosts' , 'glue_allowed_redirect_hosts' , 10 );
function glue_allowed_redirect_hosts($content){
    $content[] = 'app.realestategradschool.com';
    $content[] = 'dev-app.realestategradschool.com';
    $content[] = 'app.realestategradschool.local';
    return $content;
}
```

I've disabled all other plugins in an attempt to troubleshoot this.

Edit: I can't use login_redirect as I'm not looking to redirect ALL logins...only if the visitor is sent to the login page from a different site (using oAuth to log them in...oAuth works...just not the redirect)

Edit: Working solution:

```
function glue_login_redirect($redirect_to,$request='',$user=null){
    //using $_REQUEST because when the login form is submitted the value is in the POST
    if(isset($_REQUEST['redirect_to'])){
        $redirect_to = $_REQUEST['redirect_to'];
    }
    return $redirect_to;
}
add_filter('login_redirect','glue_login_redirect',999);
```

Comment: The other thing I have in that plugin file is a declaration of wp_validate_redirect where I copied the code from WordPress CORE and simply added a single debug statement. My issue remains wether or not this code is left intact.

Comment: Why not use `login_redirect`, did you use it already ?

Comment: Your `login_redirect` code did not work for me.

Comment: It has been a few years since this was posted, it is possible that things might have changed since then.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `login_redirect` filter. See here
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect

I think this is what you are looking for.

This will normally redirect all logins. To be able to redirect only when you want, you can use a query string parameter in the URL. Check for the parameter, if it exists redirect.

Comment: This solution forces all logins to get redirected...I only want some of them. I edited my original question with this info.

Comment: So, you can catch a query string parameter in `login_redirect` method and only redirect if that parameter fulfils your condition.
For example, in the current scenario you are getting a `redirect_to` parameter. You can get this and check if it is equal to some value, then redirect it.

Comment: This approach ended up working. I've posted my working code in the original question (as it supports formatting). I'll award the bounty as soon as I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this in your template functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'login_form' , 'glue_login_redirect' );
function glue_login_redirect() {
    global $redirect_to;
    if (!isset($_GET['redirect_to'])) {
        $redirect_to = 'YOURURLHERE';
    }
    else{
        $redirect_to = $_GET['redirect_to'];
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution forces all logins to get redirected...I only want some of them. I edited my original question with this info.

Comment: why don't you filter inside the function: IF the visitor is sent to the login page from a different site by oAuth THEN redirect according to allowed_redirect_hosts

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code help you.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
```

Its redirect users to where login from. 
example. if ya login from home page or post. 
Its login then redirect back to homepage or login page.

This code main part is :

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```